# NDepend doesn't return all methods in ASP.NET MVC Controller class

Tags: ndepend

Here is my code:

```
// <Name>test</Name>
warnif count > 0

let controllerType= ThirdParty.Types.WithFullName("System.Web.Mvc.Controller").Single()

from m in controllerType.Methods
select m
```

But I could only see these methods in `Controller`:

[image]

But clearly `View` is a method of Controller yet NDepend doesn't see it. Can any body point out what I am missing? Thanks.

[image]

[Update]

My original intent was to categorize actions according to the actual type of content they return (eg. html, fileresult, ajax result, etc) in my ASP.NET MVC code. To determine if an action returns html, I need to check if the action actually returns a `ViewResult`, including actions like the following which has a return type of `ActionResult` but actually returns `ViewResult` using the `View` method.

[image]

So I wanted to check if an action actually `IsUsingMethod(mvcViewMethod)` and as long as it calls any of the `View` method, I will consider this action as returning html. But now i couldn't get a reference to the `mvcViewMethod`.

[Update 2]

As suggested by Patrick, I checked out the class browser and only see this:

[image]

I don't see any View methods. This is much less than what I see in ILSpy of the same dll, where I can see the `View` method clearly defined:

[image]

And for an action like this:

[image]

In the class browser, if I right click this action and choose "Select methods that I use (Directly or Indirectly)", I will see this query result:

[image]

I still couldn't see it uses the `View` method.

[Final Update]

Following Patrick's suggestion, I added `System.Web.Mvc` dll into my application code dlls and it works perfectly now:

[image]

Comment: Third party assemblies only gets the members and classes actually used by your application. So here it means that only those 7 getters from Controller are actually used.

Comment: Thanks, but how is that possible? I certainly used many `return View();` statements in my actions.

Comment: @PatrickfromNDependteam I updated my question to include my original intent. I read the NDepend documentation again and still couldn't figure out why my code doesn't work.

Comment: If you get "return View(...)" the method View() is certainly referenced as a thirdparty method. You need to find it in the NDepend class browser (or with the NDepend search panel) right click > select method that use me, and then modify the generated code query with more constraints.

Comment: @PatrickfromNDependteam The class browser also only reveals those 7 methods and the `View` method is not one of them. See the [Update 2] section in the question for some details.

Comment: Could you please try adding System.Web.Mvc.dll in the list of application assemblies and see if any View(...) method gets called?  Maybe it is cleaner you come back to us at support@ndepend.com because this looks like a bug hunting request.  Thanks

Comment: @PatrickfromNDependteam It worked after adding `System.Web.Mvc` to the application dlls. Though using `notmycode` to exclude this dll and then querying from `Application` won't work but that is a minor problem. Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: you are welcome :)